# 2D raycasting top down game in unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

Im am making a pokemon like game where you walk around. 
This is a top down 2d game.
However im trying to detect a certain tile in front of me.

My character is at Y 1 and the map at Y 0. 
I have tryed to forward raycast but it didn't really work.

here is what I tried:

```
if (Input.GetKey("w") && isMoving == false)
        {
            bool disableMove = false;
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.forward, out hit, 2))
            {
                var distanceToGround = hit.distance;
                Debug.Log("HIT");

                if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "collision")
                {
                    disableMove = true;
                    Debug.Log("Tree");
                }
            }
            if (!disableMove)
            {
                Calculatewalk();
                anim.Play("WalkingUp");
                increment = 0;
                isMoving = true;
                startPoint = transform.position;
                endPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + 1);
            }
            disableMove = false;
        }
```

Comment: "didnt really work" tells us very little about the problem you're running into. Compile errors? Runtime exception? What are they? Have you Googled the error to find out what it is and why it's happening? Or is it unexpected behavior? What happened? What did you expect to happen? What have you attempted to fix this already? Please elaborate.

Comment: That will look for any tree in the looking direction no matter how far it is, you should restrict length, also, if you have your map organized in cells, is not easier to test nearby cells?

Comment: Nothing happend it didn't detect anything. I was able to walk straight past it. @tnw

Comment: Did you add a collider to your map tile?

Comment: Since it's a 2D game, are you using 2D colliders and the default Unity 2D setup? If so, you should be using [Physics2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html).Raycast, and the Vector3 would be (0,1,0) or Vector3.Up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the colliders are 2D colliders, use [Physics2D.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)

If you don't use the new Unity 2D system, we can't help you much. Perhaps you arent in the right Z layer. Also Vector3.forward seems not very good. Try to use [transform.forward](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html).

I hope I helped you!

Answer (score -3):

`xD` why do you have a `javascript` variable when you are writing in `c#`:

```
var distanceToGround = hit.distance;
```

line `7`

Comment: This should be a comment.